# SSO using WIF on UNIX/Mono

Tags: mono, wif

We have implemented SSO in a .NET web application using Windows Identity Foundation (WIF). It works great. However, we have to run it on a UNIX system using Mono. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, WIF client libraries aren't implemented in Mono.